# function inside of velocit.js sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

What is the best way to run this? I get all kind the erros

I need to add a function after the sequence is finished.

Using jquery with velocity.js

```
$(".close").click(function(){   
    var mySequence = [
        { e: $(".bt_1"),  properties: 'fadeIn'   },
        { e: $(".bt_2"), options: complete: function() { alert("123"); } }
    ];
    $.Velocity.RunSequence(mySequence); 
});
```

Comment: Your object syntax is incorrect. You need a comma between the object in the array, and I would guess that the value provided to `options` should also be an object.

Comment: Sorry, I re-edit the code. I got  (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :) and I also I ask on https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/429 and the told me the logic is good but is an invalid JS, with no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code.

Firstly, 'properties' need to have css properties, so in your case it would be 
`properties: { opacity: 1 }` to have a fadeIn effect

Also 'options' must be an object

```
options: {
            complete: function () { 
                { alert("123"); }
            } 
        }
```

Here's your corrected, working code. http://codepen.io/shubhra/pen/yyPPrp
Read the documentation - http://julian.com/research/velocity/#uiPack

Hope this helps.